# Most optimized way to reference/ use prefab in script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a world generation script that needs different prefab-blocks for different world blocks. How do I best go about referencing the prefabs in the script?

I myself have used a list (drag the prefabs into the list into unity), but this is unreliable as I need to use numbers to access them and as there is no logical order, it gets very messy as the amount of prefabs increases. Furthermore, I have used the Resources folder but this seems disadvised due to performance issues with memory management.

Therefore I wonder: what is the best way to reference a block/ prefab from the Assets folder into the final game?

Comment: "Best" is a nebulous concept and is very opinion based. But "strings" and `Resources.Load` (or the asset bundle equivalent) works.

Comment: You have that collection where you dragged all prefabs. You can reorganize it in a dictionary of name-prefabs. You then a fast way to get them. The drawback compared to Resources.Load is that your prefabs are all loaded on start, while Resources will load them when called for.